# Is it correct to use class on this sentence? I am confused.

Tags: grammar

Any student who incurs absences of more than twenty percent of the prescribed number of class and laboratory periods during the school year shall be automatically dropped from the enrollment list.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is correct, if a little confusing at first reading.  If you start with the intended meaning is "the prescribed number of classroom periods and laboratory periods", you can shorten that to "the prescribed number of class periods and laboratory periods".  Then you can shorten it again to "the prescribed number of class and laboratory periods".

The key to this sentence, which is not immediately obvious, is that "periods" refers to times spent in both class and laboratory.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a potential disagreement in your sentence which makes it a bit clunky. Checking the [definition of laboratory](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/laboratory), it can be "an academic period set aside for laboratory work" or it can be the place of such an event. Likewise [class is defined](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/class) as either a group of students, a period of study of those students, or a course of study.

Your sentence is semantically correct. IME, however, class as a singular noun is rare. The disagreement arises there. IMO, rewording it to "laboratory and class periods." clears that up. I think that "Periods of class and laboratory also works," though I do not know which is the preferred usage.

Although you've not explicitly asked about it, I'd like to call attention to the "and" in your sentence as well. There is some ambiguity here. Is it 20% of the combined number of lab sessions and class sessions? To illustrate, assume there are 10 each classes and labs, will I be disenrolled for missing 3 labs even if my class attendance is perfect? Or would I need to miss 5 labs to total more than 20% of the cumulative total? Perhaps rewording to state the number of classes plus labs or the number of classes and the number of labs which can be missed without repercussion. That might clear up the ambiguity of the word "class" as well as the doubt over whether you and is inclusive.